# Travis CI submodules and multiple .travis.yml files

Tags: git, docker, travis-ci

I have 3 repositories for a REST application:

- frontend
- backend
- compose

The `frontend` and `backend` repositories contain the code from the application.
The `compose` repository has the following structure:

- postgres
- nginx-reverse-proxy
- application

  - frontend
  - backend

both `postgres` and `nginx-reverse-proxy` contain Dockerfile and configuration files that are needed to build the components part of the application stack.
The `application` directory contains `frontend` and `backend` git submodules.

The problem I have is: I have a `.travis.yml` file for each of the submodules (`frontend` and `backend`). Now, I want to setup one for the `compose` repository, in order to build all containers including `frontend` and `backend`, in order to trigger builds separately whenever a change is made to one of this two repos.

Is there a way to re-use/reference the `.travis.yml` files from my git submodules in my root `.travis.yml` that will be in the `compose` repo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30116259/7976758

Comment: Obviously, I read the thread @phd. It's almost 5 years old and that's why I'm re-asking the same question.

Anyway, I went for another solution to avoid duplicating too much configuration in multiple .travis.yml files.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems like it's still not possible to have multiple `.yml` build configuration files.

I went for another solution:

I created bash scripts that I'm calling in the `.travis.yml` files of my submodules.
In the "main" `.travis.ym`l file of my parent repository (the one referencing submodules), I'm just calling these scripts. This way, changes to the build process are done in the bash script and are reflected on both repositories, the submodule and the parent that references submodules.